# Chrometophone example

Tags: android

I was looking to implement a C2DM Android program, I have found about chrometophone and tried to check the source from the svn. I have checked out the source from eclipse, I also have installed the app engine sdk but eclipse complains about errors in the project,the error is in the  XMPPSender when the doSendToDevice method is called, the error is "the method is not applicable for the arguments" but the arguments are correct and when I try to run the project locally I can deploy it, but when I deploy it to the app engine it doesn't work.

I have also applied 2 days earlier to projects forum for membership but no response yet.

I would like to know if someone hash managed to import the project to eclipse, and if this is a known problem, also is there any special library I have to import? in the build path there's no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there seems to be a bug in the svn's source I have changed the parameters that are passed to the doSendToDevice method, a String was passed intead of a String array.